# app engine -web application project error

Tags: gwt

when i create a new web application project it does not show the datanucleus.core.1.1.5.jar but this jar file should be exist as default. how to rectify this problem.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394334/jpa-and-gwt-failing ? Some pointers there might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it into the `WEB-INF/lib` directory manually.  Thats what I did, and it worked.

Comment: i added but it not comes under WEB-INF/lib