# How do you setup JNDI for GWT (2.0) Hosted Mode?

Tags: gwt, jakarta-ee, jndi, gwt-hosted-mode

How do you setup a JNDI server on GWT's hosted mode (they seem to use an embedded Jetty server)?

Comment: what do you mean by hosted mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to any external Java server and use it without problems with GWT (I'm assuming here that you already have a working configuration and you don't want to migrate it to GWT's embedded Jetty, [which may or may not prove to be difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364129/how-to-use-jstl-in-a-gwt-project/2365106#2365106)). For more details see the [good docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_hosted_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s).