# GWT + JSTL 1.2 : Error when use <c:forEach>

Tags: eclipse, jsp, gwt, jstl, tomcat7

I can't solve this issue.
I've read the post in
 [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364129/how-to-use-jstl-in-a-gwt-project) , but I don't use Maven dependencies.

There's another solution? Even for me, the project works after deploy in Tomcat, but in dev mode on Eclipse I have a 500 error.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the `jstl.jar` added in classpath?

Comment: Yes of course... jstl 1.2

Comment: I've read in the web, that perhaps the problem is Jetty but I don't know.

Comment: Yes I will test it at my end. I'll tell you once got some time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a big problem and find a solution is very important.